# Exporting from one schema and importing to another with pg_dump

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `units`, which exists in two separate schemas within the same database (we'll call them `old_schema`, and `new_schema`). The structure of the table in both schemas are identical. The only difference is that the `units` table in `new_schema` is presently empty.

I am attempting to export the data from this table in `old_schema` and import it into `new_schema`. I used `pg_dump` to handle the export, like so:

```
pg_dump -U username -p 5432 my_database -t old_schema.units -a > units.sql
```

I then attempted to import it using the following:

```
psql -U username -p 5432 my_database -f units.sql
```

Unfortunately, this appeared to try and reinsert back in to the `old_schema`. Looking at the generated sql file, it seems there is a line, which I think is causing this:

```
SET search_path = mysql_migration, pg_catalog;
```

I can, in fact, alter this line to read

```
SET search_path = public;
```

And this does prove successful, but I don't believe this is the "correct" way to accomplish this.

**Question:** When importing data via a script generated through pg_dump, how can I specify in to which schema the data should go without altering the generated file?

Comment: Note: I'm still somewhat new to postgres, but I hope this is not a massively basic question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main issues here based on the scenario you described.

1. The *difference in the schemas*, to which you alluded.
2. The fact that by dumping the whole table via *pg_dump*, you're dumping the table definition also, which will cause issues if the table is already present in the destination schema.

To dump only the data, if the table already exists in the destination database (which appears to be the case based on your scenario above), you can dump the table using *pg_dump* with the `--data-only` flag.

Then, to address the schema issue, I would recommend doing a search/replace (*sed* would be a quick way to do it) on the output *sql* file, replacing `old_schema` with `new_schema`.

That way, it will apply the data (which is all that would be in the file, not the table definition itself) to the table in `new_schema`.

If you need a solution on a broader level to support, say, dynamically named schemas, you can use the same search/replace trick with *sed*, but instead of replacing it with `new_schema`, replace it with some placeholder text, say, `$$placeholder_schema$$` (something highly unlikely to appear as as token elsewhere in the file), and then, when you need to apply that file to a particular schema, use the original file as a template, copy it, and then modify the copy using *sed* or similar, replacing the placeholder token with the desired on-the-fly schema name.

You can set some options for *psql* on the command line, such as `--set AUTOCOMMIT=off`, however, a similar approach with `SEARCH_PATH` does not appear to have any effect.

Instead, it needs the form `\set SEARCH_PATH to <path>`, which can be specified with the `-c` option, but not in combination with `-f` (it's either or).

Given that, I think modifying the file with *sed* is probably the best all around option  in this case for use with `-f`.

Comment: Alright, fair enough, thank you. I'll check out sed; probably a lot easier than vi for this purpose... I am somewhat surprised at the restriction on the `-c` option with `-f`. Do you happen to know the reason they wrote it that way?

Comment: Sure, no problem. Re: why, I'm not sure, but off the cuff, I would suspect it's at least in part because each one is a self-contained set of commands, and allowing both at once would open up questions as to which one to apply first, which would then require more options, etc.

Comment: That seems logical, since as you say the script contains its own environment metadata. Thank you again for the thorough answer.